# How do other websites detect my DNS leaks?

Tags: vpn, dns, internet

There are websites on the internet that discover if, when using a VPN, you expose DNS leaks to your ISP like dnsleaktest.com

My question basically boils down to this: how do these services work?
I understand that a DNS leak is when you request a certain hostname to be resolved to an IP address so that you can connect to it via the internet but, unbeknownst to you, this request gets sent to a computer that your ISP controls and which may record your request without you even finding out about this. This means that, even when you have a VPN, a DNS leak could expose to your ISP what websites you tried to access.

And yet, if that was the case, only the ISP should know if you have those leaks or not, yet the aforementioned web services can clearly see that information as well, almost as if it was public. They can even point to the exact DNS servers that you use. I would think that even your browser wouldn't have access to these details since the DNS servers that you connect to seems like something the operating system would keep track of, yet they seem to be public information.

Comment: In addition to using the VPN, also configure your computer and router to override isp’s DNS, I’d suggest using Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1... more into at https://1.1.1.1 (no .com needed)

Comment: Thanks! I already did that though. Now I'm curious to know how websites that I visit can detect what DNS servers I use (their IPs, specifically).

Comment: I’m not clear exactly what’s happening to you, however I could also block those outbound requests at the router, YMMV tho... a lot of routers don’t have that built into the GUI.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the following: suppose I have a VPN enabled. I try to connect to facebook.com. Since I didn't set the DNS server, my request goes to my ISP's server to resolve it into an IP. Consequently, my ISP now knows that I tried to contact facebook.com even though I have a VPN. Afterwards, I go to dnsleaktest.com and it finds the IP address of my ISP's DNS server since this is the one that my computer used. How did it find this IP address? Did it ask my web browser to get the IP address? Or did it find it in a different way?

Comment: It’s hard to say how your computer is configured or mis-configured.  Do you in fact know your settings/configuration is sending web browsing thru the VPN tunnel?

Comment: I don't really know. I assume something in my system is leaking which DNS servers I use. I just don't know what that is. Maybe it's my browser, maybe it's something else. I don't know